# Dragging INDIRECT and

Tags: excel, delete-row, excel-indirect

I thought I would take you through my thinking as there may be a better way than using INDIRECT to achieve the desired result but if not then a solution with indirect would be very handy.

I had a simple formula

`=SUMPRODUCT($E$10:$E20,J10:J20)` Dragged across a great number of columns ending somewhere in the CC's

However I found when I inserted a row it would change my 10 and $10 to 11 and $11, so i placed an indirect in there.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("$E$10:$E20"),INDIRECT("J10:J20"))
```

I now realize that I'm referring to a string and if I drag this across to the right, the cell references won't update.

So initially my first question was how could I go about updating these so that I can drag the `INDIRECT` across the columns to the right and update the cell references so that my formula would resemble or at least work in the same way when dragged into column K and so on.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("$E$10:$E20"),INDIRECT("K10:K20"))
```

HOWEVER

If There is a better solution than the indirect to keep my orignial formula when rows are inserted or deleted that would be very helpful too.

Comment: a) Where are you inserting the row? b) Should $E$10:$E10 be $E$10:$E20 (in two places)?

Comment: apologies, you are absolutely correct, that was supposed to be $E$10:$E$20, my mistake

Comment: I'm not sure why you used $E$10:$E20 and not $E$10:$E$20 in the original formula. Was row 20 intended to expand to 21 when a row was inserted while row 10 remained static?

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I think that was a result of to much coffee, and staring unsuccessfully at excel for the last couple of hours, I just missed the $20

You have been a great help and saved me from a major case of defenestration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have turned both rows and columns into static string representations when you really want to only guard the row designations from changing on a row insert. Replacing your [INDIRECT functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) with [INDEX functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) will allow you to make column E absolute with a conventional *$* and leave column J relative as well as hard-code the referenced rows so they will not change on a row insert.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX($E:$E, 10):INDEX($E:$E, 20)), (INDEX(J:J, 10):INDEX(J:J, 20)))
```

Just don't insert any columns and everything should work as planned.

On a related note, referring to "$E$10:$E20" as a string in INDIRECT may help visually identify its purpose but as you've noted, the text is not going to change despite dragging to a new location or inserting rows. There is no difference if you use INDIRECT("E10:E20").

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going to try that now

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the very last problem I had in a rather large project (for me). Life saver

Comment: Well as soon as I up my rep, ill up your answer. Have a great day Jeeped